# How can I substitute everything between two markers AND the markers themselves?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a substring:

```
<RECALL>First_Name</RECALL>
```

I want to substitute that entire substring with another value "John":

```
value = "John"
string = "My name is <RECALL>First_Name</RECALL>"
```

I parsed it using Crack, but now need to make a substitution.

I did the following:

```
string.gsub(/<RECALL>(.*)<\/RECALL>/, value)
```

I got the result I desired, but was wondering if there are better ways to do this?

Comment: Do you have to use the `<RECALL></RECALL>` syntax, or are you free to use a different "placeholder" in your "template"?  Hint hint :) use a template library :)

Comment: what is a template library?  I would like to use the `<tag>` since `crack` automatically parses it.

Comment: Check out https://rubygems.org/gems/erubis

Answer (score 2):

Like Jared said, I'd strongly encourage you to find a templating library if you can, but if you can't...

```
> str = "Hi, <RECALL>First_Name</RECALL>. Your last name is <RECALL>Last_Name</RECALL>. Your are <RECALL>Age</RECALLL> years old."
=> "Hi, <RECALL>First_Name</RECALL>. Your last name is <RECALL>Last_Name</RECALL>. Your are <RECALL>Age</RECALLL> years old."

> subs = {'First_Name' => 'John', 'Last_Name' => 'Doe'}
=> {"First_Name"=>"John", "Last_Name"=>"Doe"}

> str.gsub(%r!<RECALL>(.*?)</RECALL>!) {|m| subs.fetch($1, m)}
=> "Hi, John. Your last name is Doe. Your are <RECALL>Age</RECALLL> years old."
```

Note that I intentionally didn't provide an 'Age' substitution so that one stays in the string.  You could do other things like raise an error, etc.

Comment: I believe you can simplify your block to `{ subs[$1] }`. Consider adding an `'Age'` key to `subs`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland You could, but you'd lose the functionality of outputting "recall tags" you don't have a valid substitution for as `subs['Age']` will return nil.  Probably not what we want.

Comment: I thought you had just inadvertently left out an `Age` key (and returning `<RECALL>Age</RECALLL>` didn't seem like what was wanted), but I see your point. I presume you could also write the block `{|m| subs[$1] || m}`.  Angela, if you always wanted to replace all the values, you'd be wise to confirm they all appear in `subs` as keys, in which case you could use the block `{ subs[$1] }` if you wanted. btw, that +1 was from me. :-)